# How to merge the values of two objects into one object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array of objects,those all objects are same object. But finally I need to put all those values of an object into single object.These are my objects.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Permissions Object
        (
            [modules] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [submodules] => Array
                (
                )

            [operations] => Array
                (
                    [3M] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [4M] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Permissions Object
        (
            [modules] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [submodules] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 7
                    [5] => 8
                )

            [operations] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                    [3M] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Create
                            [1] => Read
                            [2] => Update
                            [3] => Delete
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before or after merging you just have to Remove duplicate values.

```
$array1 = [ 
        "modules" => [ 
            0 => 2, 1 => 4
            ], 
        "submodules" => [
            "3m" => [
                0 => "create", 1 => "read"
                ], 
            "4m" => [0 => "create", 1 => "read"
                ]
        ]
    ];

$array2 = [ 
    "modules" => [ 
        0 => 1, 
        1 => 3
        ], 
    "submodules" => [
        "1m" => [
            0 => "create", 1 => "read"
            ], 
        "10m" => [
            0 => "create", 1 => "read"
            ]
    ]
];

$merged = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
print_r($merged);

Array ( [modules] => Array ( 
[0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 1 [3] => 3 
) 
[submodules] => Array ( 
[3m] => Array ( [0] => create [1] => read 
    ) 
[4m] => 
    Array ( [0] => create [1] => read 
        ) 
[1m] => Array (
    [0] => create [1] => read 
    ) 
[10m] => Array ( 
[0] => create [1] => read 
    ) 
)
```

)

Comment: can you give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use array_merge, you can use a workaround as follows:

```
$global; //your array
$merged = array(); //the array you want with the merged objects
foreach ($global as $k => $object) {
    foreach ($object as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $val)
            $merged[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
```